# Problems with VS Code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I am not sure if this is really a problem with VS Code or not. I use the Fetch API in JavaScript. When I run the Fetch directly in JavaScript with a Chrome browser (not Node.JS), I have no problems. The Fetch API executes fine. A very important point is that I don't see an OPTIONS request being sent. However, when I run the same Fetch using exactly the same JavaScript (using VS Code) I do see an OPTIONS being sent. Even worse, the Fetch (under JavaScript, under Chrome, under VS Code) does not wait for the OPTIONS to complete. The Fetch just fails with a 'Failed to fetch' error. I don't understand this. Why should VS Code make any difference? What am I doing wrong? What additional information should I provide? How should this problem be debugged?

In the VSC environment, I run the code using F5 (under the Run menu, it means 'Start Debugging'). When I run my code outside of VSC, I don't see anything under Network (no OPTIONS request). When I run my code under VSC, I see CORS failures in the console. Why do I get an OPTIONS request under VSC, but no OPTIONS outside of VSC?

I have learned some more about this. The OPTIONS HTTP request seems to be related to using HTTP headers. If I get rid of the HTTP headers the OPTIONS HTTP request goes away. However, the POST HTTP request still fails with 'Failed to fetch'. See the code below.

```js
    /* The commented out code passes a set of headers to the server. Testing
       and logic shows that the headers are not needed. */
    if (1 == 2) {
      apiPromise = fetch(urlStr, { 
                                   credentials: "include",
                                   "method": "POST",
                                   "headers": apiHeaders,
                                   "body": apiJson
                                 });
    }
    apiPromise = fetch(urlStr, { 
                                 credentials: "include",
                                 "method": "POST", 
                                 "body": apiJson
                               });
    /* Return the promise to the caller */
    /* console.log(apiPromise); */
    /* console.log(typeof (apiPromise)); */
    return apiPromise;
```

Comment: The difference is how you're running JS. What Node version do you have? Node didn't have native `fetch` before v18 I think.

Comment: "*when I run the same Fetch using exactly the same JavaScript (using VS Code)*" - how exactly are you using vs code to run the code?

Comment: The OPTIONS request is most likely a CORS preflight request.

Comment: A few answers. I am not using Node (at least I don't think so). I am running JavaScript in a Chrome browser. I run my JS code using F5 (under Run, F5 for 'Start Debugging'). The OPTIONS request is probably CORS related. But why do I get it in some cases, but not others?

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. Give us exact details and a procedure to minimally reproduce the behaviour you're observing. Show us also what you see in your network tabin Chrome devtools and any related error messages in the console.

Comment: what is the domain of the page in which you send the fetch request in each case?

Comment: "*I run my JS code using F5*" - which [launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) are you using for that?

Comment: "*When I run my code under VSC*" - does that mean a Chrome browser window (or tab) launched by VSC? If yes, please post the URLs you see in the address bar in both the VSC-launched run and when you "*run the Fetch directly in JavaScript with a Chrome browser*"

Comment: please show exact error messages and request details.

Comment: please respond to our request for further clarifications. not having those details is potentially blocking you from getting better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I added what follows to my launch.json file and the problem went away.

"runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security","--user-date-dir=c:\chrome-browser"]

Putting all these things together, it looks like when I ran without VSC, CORS is/was somehow (automatically? partially?) disabled. When I run inside VSC, CORS is not disabled. As a consequence, CORS must be manually disabled. At least this explanation fits the facts. What is really going on, I don’t know.

Answer (score -1):

Check for any additional code differences: Ensure that there are no code differences between the version of your JavaScript code running in VS Code and the one you tested directly in the browser. Any inconsistencies in the code could potentially cause issues.

The behavior you are experiencing with the Fetch API in VS Code might be related to a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issue. CORS is a security feature implemented by web browsers to prevent web pages from making requests to a different domain than the one serving the web page.

Debugging in the browser: If you want to debug the issue within the browser while running your code from VS Code, you can open the Chrome Developer Tools (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I) and go to the "Network" tab. There, you can see the request and response headers, including any CORS-related issues.

Comment: I am literally running the same code. Not similar code. The same code. Of course, I am getting different results. Not at all clear why. Of course, CORS could be a problem. However, I don't even get that far. Why do I see an OPTIONS request under VSC, but not natively? I don't know.

Comment: So put your code here

Comment: YS, Other folks told me to add my code to the original problem. I have done that (or at least I hope I have).

Answer (score -1):

Any extensions in VS Code that could be affecting network requests or execution environments? Try disabling them. Sounds like different environments or runtimes could be the problem. Check for differences? Hope that helps!

Comment: Good theory. I tried disabling all of my VSC extensions and it did not help.

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds like you don't think CORS is the issue either. Good luck!

Comment: AE, Somehow I do think CORS is the underlying problem (in some way). What I don't get is why everything just works outside of VSC and fails inside VSC.